# Django foreign key value from template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, foreign-keys

I've looked through other answers to similar questions but I can't seem to get it to work. here is my model structure:

```
models.py

class Seller(models.Model):
    seller_full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    seller_listing_name = models.CharField(max_length=50) <-- I want to display this in template
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.seller_listing_name

# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

In my view I get a query set of products

```
views.py

def store(request):
    products = Product.objects.values().order_by('?') # shuffle order
    args = {'products': products}
    return render(request, 'store/products-page.html', args)
```

In the template I iterate through products and build cards that display item details. I want to also display the listing name of the seller for each product on each card. I cannot seem to get the foreign key statement correct in the view because it renders empty where the sellers name should be.

```
products-page.html

{% for product in products %}
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
    ...
        <p>
            // {{ product.seller.seller_listing_name }} // <-- display sellers name here
        </p> 
        <h4 class="card-title">
            <a href="#">{{ product.product_name }}</a>
        </h4>
        <p>#{{ product.product_id }}</p>
        <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
        <h5>${{ product.price | floatformat:2 }}</h5>
    ...
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I've been messing with this for awhile and I can't seem to get it so any help would be awesome!

**EDIT**
Some links I've looked at:

[Django: How to get data connected by ForeignKey via Template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056844/django-how-to-get-data-connected-by-foreignkey-via-template)

[Django foreign key relation in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281965/django-foreign-key-relation-in-template)

[How to access foreign key table's data in Django templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58205608/how-to-access-foreign-key-tables-data-in-django-templates)

**SOLUTION**
Thanks to the comments below I didn't realize that I was converting the products to a dictionary using .order_by('?') - This was resulting in a data structure that didn't keep my relationships so I wasn't able to access my FK.

views.py

```
def store(request):
    products = Product.objects.order_by('?') # REMOVE .values()
    args = {'products': products}
    return render(request, 'store/products-page.html', args)
```

products-page.html

```
{% for product in products %}
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
    ...
        <p>
            // {{ product.seller.seller_listing_name }} // <-- display sellers name here
        </p> 
        <h4 class="card-title">
            <a href="#">{{ product.product_name }}</a>
        </h4>
        <p>#{{ product.product_id }}</p>
        <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
        <h5>${{ product.price | floatformat:2 }}</h5>
    ...
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of ForeignKey you need to add something like

```
{% for product in products %}
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
    [...]
        {% for seller in product.seller_set.all %}
        <p>
            // {{ seller.seller_listing_name }} // <-- display sellers name here
        </p> 
        {% endfor %}
        <h4 class="card-title">
            <a href="#">{{ product.product_name }}</a>
        </h4>
    [...]
```

Comment: I've tried this and it never enters the for loop so the p-tag never renders. I just tried again and the same thing happened.

Comment: When the yellow debug screen is up, I can see local vars which includes the products query set. In that it has 'seller_id' with the correct reference to the seller name that I want. Maybe there is a way I can use the ID I do have to get the name another way?

Comment: BTW why you are using ```products = Product.objects.values().order_by('?')``` in view? You create dict from Product model?

Comment: Yeah I want the order of the products to shuffle each time the view renders. I didn't realize that might have something to do with it since nothing else is being affected but now I think it might be... I can try to remove that and see if that helps

Comment: Try ```Product.objects.order_by('?')```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't even think about that so I'm glad I kept that part of the code in my post. Updated my questions with working solution! Thanks!!